# Java float to long Typecast

Tags: java, type-conversion

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here. I am able to typecast y into long, but the same doesn't work for x/y.

```
class Test {

long convert(int x, float y) {
    //return (long) x/y; // cannot convert from float to long
    return (long)y;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The only issue here is how things are parenthesized.  You'd be fine if you wrote

```
return (long) (x / y);
```

When you wrote `(long) x / y`, that was treated as `((long) x) / y`, which is a `float` according to the typing rules of Java.

Answer (score 4):

Here

```
return (long) x/y;
```

You are casting `x` as `long` but the entire expression is still `float` because of `y` and hence when you try to return it , it shows error. It is same as `return ((long)x/y);`

Better :

```
return (long) (x/y);
```